# Create matrix with elements returned by a function

Tags: r

I have two vectors x and y with some values and I need to generate the matrix which elements would be returned by a function f(x,y) applied to those 2 vectors. That is the matrix M will have a typical element

```
M[i,j] <- f(x[i], y[j])
```

What is the most efficent way to do this if I want to avoid loops? I can generate matrix columns or rows by using sapply function, i.e.

```
M[i, ] <- sapply(y, f, x = x[i])
```

But I still need to apply loop in other dimension which is very slow, because the dimension of x is huge. Is it possible to use apply family of function and avoid loops completely?

Comment: Can `f` be vectorized?

Comment: If `f` is vectorized `outer(x,y,"f")`, else `outer(x,y,FUN=Vectorize(f))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is exactly what the `outer` function does:

```
outer(x, y, f)
```

If `f` is not vectorized, you need:

```
outer(x, y, Vectorize(f))
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the function     f    has 3 arguments,    f(x,y,z)    but we only need to use the first 2 and to have    z = 1    ?

Comment: Just add the third argument: `outer( x, y, f, z=1 )`.